# Cannot create and build Kotlin Multiplatform Shared Module in existing Android codebase

Tags: android, kotlin, gradle, kotlin-multiplatform

I am trying to follow this tutorial for Android application works on iOS using Kotlin Multiplatform.

https://www.jetbrains.com/help/kotlin-multiplatform-dev/multiplatform-integrate-in-existing-app.html#make-your-code-cross-platform

Basically my goal is to reuse the business logic Kotlin code in existing Android code so our team can experiment on new iPhone user base.

However after I tried the step for adding new **Kotlin Multiplatform Shared Module**. It cannot compile.

The error is

```
Unresolved reference: libs
```

I tried comparing with the source code they provided.

https://github.com/Kotlin/kmm-integration-sample/tree/final

It seems that the Android Studio version and/or the Gradle version of the sample code is outdated.

My code of `shared/build.gradle.kts` is below

```
plugins {
    alias(libs.plugins.kotlinMultiplatform)
    alias(libs.plugins.androidLibrary)
}

kotlin {
    androidTarget {
        compilations.all {
            kotlinOptions {
                jvmTarget = "1.8"
            }
        }
    }
    
    listOf(
        iosX64(),
        iosArm64(),
        iosSimulatorArm64()
    ).forEach {
        it.binaries.framework {
            baseName = "shared"
            isStatic = true
        }
    }

    sourceSets {
        commonMain.dependencies {
            //put your multiplatform dependencies here
        }
        commonTest.dependencies {
            implementation(libs.kotlin.test)
        }
    }
}

android {
    namespace = "net.petrabarus.poc.android.shared"
    compileSdk = 34
    defaultConfig {
        minSdk = 24
    }
    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility = JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
        targetCompatibility = JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    }
}
```

while the code of `shared/build.gradle.kts` in the sample code is below.

```
plugins {
    kotlin("multiplatform")
    id("com.android.library")
}

kotlin {
    android()
    
    listOf(
        iosX64(),
        iosArm64(),
        iosSimulatorArm64()
    ).forEach {
        it.binaries.framework {
            baseName = "shared"
        }
    }

    sourceSets {
        val commonMain by getting
        val commonTest by getting {
            dependencies {
                implementation(kotlin("test"))
            }
        }
        val androidMain by getting
        val androidTest by getting
        val iosX64Main by getting
        val iosArm64Main by getting
        val iosSimulatorArm64Main by getting
        val iosMain by creating {
            dependsOn(commonMain)
            iosX64Main.dependsOn(this)
            iosArm64Main.dependsOn(this)
            iosSimulatorArm64Main.dependsOn(this)
        }
        val iosX64Test by getting
        val iosArm64Test by getting
        val iosSimulatorArm64Test by getting
        val iosTest by creating {
            dependsOn(commonTest)
            iosX64Test.dependsOn(this)
            iosArm64Test.dependsOn(this)
            iosSimulatorArm64Test.dependsOn(this)
        }
    }
}

android {
    compileSdk = 31
    sourceSets["main"].manifest.srcFile("src/androidMain/AndroidManifest.xml")
    defaultConfig {
        minSdk = 21
        targetSdk = 31
    }
}
```

It seems that the newest one uses the shared dependency configuration from Gradle.

https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/platforms.html

I added this `libs.versions.toml` below from the KMM Project Wizard

https://kmp.jetbrains.com/

```
[versions]
agp = "8.2.0"
kotlin = "1.9.22"

[plugins]
androidLibrary = { id = "com.android.library", version.ref = "agp" }
kotlinMultiplatform = { id = "org.jetbrains.kotlin.multiplatform", version.ref = "kotlin" }
```

The error is now like below

```
Error resolving plugin [id: 'org.jetbrains.kotlin.multiplatform', version: '1.9.22']
> The request for this plugin could not be satisfied because the plugin is already on the classpath with an unknown version, so compatibility cannot be checked.
```

This is the code

https://github.com/petrabarus/poc-android-export-kmm-module-to-maven/tree/add-shared

What did I do wrong, and how do I fix this?

The Android Studio I am using is below

```
Android Studio Hedgehog | 2023.1.1
Build #AI-231.9392.1.2311.11076708, built on November 9, 2023
Runtime version: 17.0.7+0-17.0.7b1000.6-10550314 aarch64
VM: OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM by JetBrains s.r.o.
macOS 14.2.1
GC: G1 Young Generation, G1 Old Generation
Memory: 1024M
Cores: 8
Metal Rendering is ON
Registry:
    external.system.auto.import.disabled=true
    ide.text.editor.with.preview.show.floating.toolbar=false

Non-Bundled Plugins:
    com.jetbrains.kmm (0.8.2(231)-25)
    org.jetbrains.compose.desktop.ide (1.6.0)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I tried to match the dependencies and version of the libraries from the `shared/build.gradle.kts`, root `build.gradle.kts` and `libs.versions.toml`

```
// gradle/libs.versions.toml
[versions]
agp = "8.2.0"
kotlin = "1.9.0"

[plugins]
androidLibrary = { id = "com.android.library", version.ref = "agp" }
kotlinMultiplatform = { id = "org.jetbrains.kotlin.multiplatform", version.ref = "kotlin" }
```

```
//build.gradle.kts
// Top-level build file where you can add configuration options common to all sub-projects/modules.
plugins {
    id("com.android.library") version "8.2.0" apply false
    id("com.android.application") version "8.2.0" apply false
    id("org.jetbrains.kotlin.android") version "1.9.0" apply false
    id("org.jetbrains.kotlin.multiplatform") version "1.9.0" apply false
}
```

Now the error change to

```
Build was configured to prefer settings repositories over project repositories but repository 'ivy' was added by build file 'shared/build.gradle.kts'
```

The problem is in these lines

```
    listOf(
        iosX64(),
        iosArm64(),
        iosSimulatorArm64()
    ).forEach {
        it.binaries.framework {
            baseName = "shared"
            isStatic = true
        }
    }
```

Finally I tried matching the `settings.gradle.kts` with the KMM Project Wizard.

Previous is

```
pluginManagement {
    repositories {
        google()
        mavenCentral()
        gradlePluginPortal()
    }
}
dependencyResolutionManagement {
    repositoriesMode.set(RepositoriesMode.FAIL_ON_PROJECT_REPOS)
    repositories {
        google()
        mavenCentral()
    }
}
```

Now is

```
pluginManagement {
    repositories {
        maven("https://maven.pkg.jetbrains.space/public/p/compose/dev")
        google()
        mavenCentral()
        gradlePluginPortal()
    }
}
dependencyResolutionManagement {
    //repositoriesMode.set(RepositoriesMode.FAIL_ON_PROJECT_REPOS)
    repositories {
        google()
        mavenCentral()
        maven("https://maven.pkg.jetbrains.space/public/p/compose/dev")
    }
}
```

The build runs! I am not sure why, but it runs!